# Pidgin/Empathy are not recognizing webcam

Tags: webcam, screensaver

i'm new to ubuntu and am having some issues doing a few things. I'm trying to video chat on yahoo but am having trouble getting pidgin or empathy to recognize my webcam. I also can't figure out how to customize or change the screensavers . Any help would be appreciated. Thanx to all

Comment: You might want to split your questions, You might also give more information on your webcam. Its been a while but you'd also want to check if either IM client supports video, since it often lags on third part clients

Answer (score 0):

If you want to audio/video chat , its better if you try Google Hangouts/Gmail chat/FB chat directly from browser instead of pidgin/empathy clients. If you want to use a client, Skype is good.

Which version of Ubuntu are you using ? Check this - http://www.howtogeek.com/114027/how-to-add-screensavers-to-ubuntu-12.04/

Comment: i'm on 12.10. practically fresh install . installed restricted extras and java/flash plugins . that's about it .

Comment: Are you able to access webcam from Webbrowser Gmail/Fb clients ?